# Android SDK version 7.0 not found - Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I have a problem to run my app for Android ... I downloaded all the SDK's Android (including 7) and continues the error below:

[image]

Below the print from my folder android sdk, android settings titanium and SDK Manager Android:

[image: Appcelerator Preferences]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 7.0 is not yet supported by Titanium SDK 6.0.0.GA, but it may work.

To verify your problem - run ***appc ti info -t android***  command from terminal and see if your Android 7.0 is detected or not.

And make sure JDK 1.8 installed in the system which is required by Android 7.0